# Click Through a Nested Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm inflating a scrolling fragment inside another fragment, and the scrolling nested fragment allow to see the top of the parent fragment, like this:

[image]

Parent Fragment:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_vector_test"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:tint="@color/black" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/container_overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Nested Fragment:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.main.BlankFragment" 
android:clickable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="80dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_top"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_top">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_room1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#848484"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"/>

            .
            .
            .

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_top"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_top" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The Nested layout is the purple one and the top white part is the Parent Fragment.

My problem is that I would like to make the arrow clickable through the nested fragment but I don't have any idea how to do this. I've tried making `clickable = "false"` the ConstraintLayout inside the NestedScrollableLayout...but it doesn't work

My gut tells me that it has to be something easy but I can't think any workaround.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Is the white area where the arrow is located always supposed to be visible.?

Comment: @avalerio I've update the image with a gif, there you can see the behaviour of the nested fragment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can place scrollable fragment inside another fragment also you can make arrow clickable through fragment.but you can't scroll child fragment up to parent fragment top .because fragmentContainerView need to be bottom of arrow view if you want to set arrow visible.so code behind this layout would be single fragment with Bottom sheet and arrow on top.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>       
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_vector_test"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tint="@color/black" />
    
    
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    
        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    
                    app:behavior_hideable="false"
                    app:behavior_peekHeight="700dp"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                     app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
    
    
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/card_room1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="#848484"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp" />
    
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/card_room2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="#848484"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp" />
    
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/card_room3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="#848484"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp" />
    
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/card_room4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="#848484"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp" />
    
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/card_room5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="#848484"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp" />
    
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/card_room6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="#848484"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp" />
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/card_room7"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="#848484"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp" />
    
                </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


//MainActivity code

  BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheet;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);

        bottomSheet = BottomSheetBehavior.from(rootLayout);

        bottomSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

          }
```

[image]

Comment: Already tried that but my problem is that I have the half circle shape at top and when it's at the same altitude as the arrow, it will be covered by the nested fragment...so it won't be clickable.

Comment: Yes at that point only  it won't clickable and it's impossible to implement.if you want you can restrict bottom view hight then it's clickable.@Buntupana.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no easy way to make this work in your current implementation, the reason is that `NestedScrollView` consumes all touch events if it has child views.

An easier way could be to implement the arrow as part of an `AppBar` within the fragment that hosts the `NestedScrollView` except you'd have to wrap it inside a root `CoordinatorLayout`

Use `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` on the `NestedScrollView` and `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` on the toolbar to achieve the desired effect.

Please check the documentation for more information - https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/AppBarLayout